# Invalid views not showing in user_dependencies after first compilation

Tags: oracle, view, dependencies, data-dictionary

When I create an (invalid) view that selects from another invalid view, the view does not immediately show up in `user_dependencies`. I am wondering if this is expected.

These are the steps to reproduce the behavior:

First, I create a table

```
create table tq84_t (
  col_1 number,
  col_2 number
);
```

Then I create a view that is dependent on the table. Note the typo `col_22` instead of `col_2`:

```
create or replace force view tq84_v as select col_1, col_22 from tq84_t;
```

Of course, this view will be created in an invalid state:

```
Warning: View created with compilation errors.
```

I create another view which is dependent on `tq84_v` (which will also be in an invalid state):

```
create force view tq84_v2 as select * from tq84_v;
```

I now query `user_dependencies` to check whether I have objects that are dependent on `tq84_v`. I would have expected `TQ84_V2` to be reported, but the following query returns no record:

```
select name from user_dependencies where referenced_name = 'TQ84_V';
```

I re-compile the second view:

```
alter view tq84_v2 compile;
```

and query `user_dependencies` again:

```
select name from user_dependencies where referenced_name = 'TQ84_V';
```

Only this time, Oracle will report `TQ84_V2` as being dependent on `TQ84_V`.

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: Weird behavior. Not sure what you expect to get out of this question here though. Open a support ticket if this is bothering you, but dependency info for invalid objects shouldn't be relied upon in any case.

Comment: Yes, i think that is correct as dependency data is populated after object is compiled and marked valid. You probably can test this by tracing the steps and see when sys.dependency$ experiences DML.